# When are definite integrals of continuous functions pairwise distinct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f_1, \ldots, f_n : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a finite family of (positive) continuous functions.

I was wondering about the weakest condition to impose on the $f_i$ so as to  guarantee that

$$\tag{1}\exists\, \text 0\leq s < t \leq 1 \quad \text{ s.t. } \ \text{ the numbers} \quad q_i(s,t):=\int_s^t\!f_i(u)\,\mathrm{d}u, \ \ i=1,\ldots, n, \quad \text{ are pairwise distinct}? $$

(In case someone's in doubt: This is *not* a homework question.)

Comment: If there's a point where all the $f_n$ take different values, then by continuity there is an interval on which they all take different values on the whole interval. Then integrating along this interval should give different values for the integrals. I haven't worked out the details though, and I'm not sure if this is as weak a condition as you can get (though it feels very weak)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I had the same thought and added the details. I also can't think of a weaker condition.

Comment: Easy to have

$$\int_0^1 f_1 < \int_0^1 f_2 <\cdots <\int_0^1 f_n$$

such that for each $x\in [0,1],$ $\{f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\}$ has no more that two elements:

Comment: @zhw Yes, of course - but the question was asking for a sufficient condition for strict inequalities between integrals.

Answer (score 3):

I would think of a statement like this one:

> Assume there exists a $x\in[0,1]$ such that the $f_i(x)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ are pairwise distinct. Then there is an $\varepsilon>0$, such that the numbers
> $$ \int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_i(t)dt \qquad\mbox{for}\ i=1,\ldots,n $$
> are pairwise distinct.

The proof goes like this: W.l.o.g. assume $f_1(x)< f_2(x)<\cdots \le f_n(x)$. Then, by continuity of the functions $f_i$, there is an $\varepsilon>0$, such that
$$f_1(t)<f_2(t)<\cdots<f_n(t) \qquad\mbox{holds for all}\ t\in(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap[0,1].$$
This immediately yields
$$ \int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_1(t)dt\le \int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_2(t)dt\le\cdots\le\int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_n(t)dt,  $$
by monotonicity of the integral. To prove these inequalities are strict, assume that $$\int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_k(t)dt = \int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}f_{k+1}(t)dt \quad\Longrightarrow \int_{\max(0,x-\varepsilon)}^{\min(1,x+\varepsilon)}(f_{k+1}(t)-f_k(t))dt=0. $$
Therefore, $f_{k+1}(t)=f_k(t)$ for almost every $t\in(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap[0,1]$, which is a contradiction to the above strict inequality.